# Plotting time series in Y axis of the excel sheet

Tags: excel

Its excel-2013. I have some data points as below.I want to be able to show the start time, finish time of a particular job for a specific date in a excel sheet. And i want to do it for ~30 days of a month. But when i plot it using simple line chart, its not detecting and plotting the exact the 'start time' in Y axis. Can you guide me here , how i can do this?

[image]

Date    Start Time  Finish Time Duration

1-Jan-20    1/2/2020 2:48   1/2/2020 7:12   4.4

2-Jan-20    1/3/2020 2:34   1/3/2020 8:25   5.85

3-Jan-20    1/4/2020 3:14   1/4/2020 9:04   5.84

4-Jan-20    1/5/2020 1:19   1/5/2020 5:50   4.52

5-Jan-20    1/6/2020 2:29   1/6/2020 6:39   4.16

6-Jan-20    1/7/2020 2:14   1/7/2020 8:22   6.15

I tried to use line chart but in that the Y axis i.e the start time value is converted to number automatically. And even formatting that to the time data type is not helping.Its coming something as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IEuj.png)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing a Gantt chart.  Those are used for project management.  Excel doesn't have a simple way to make Gantt charts.  (MS Project is another Micro Soft application, and it does.)  But I did find a  link to an Excel template, and there are other templates our there as well.  Just search "Excel Gantt".

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/present-your-data-in-a-gantt-chart-in-excel-f8910ab4-ceda-4521-8207-f0fb34d9e2b6